# Создаёт ли копию new Function() и нагружает ли она память для серверного ПО?

Tags: c#, функции, tcp

Всем привет !
начал писать простенький TCP сервер
и столкнулся с очень любопытной ситуацией
посоветовали использовать интересный метод , но ранее
я никогда него не использовал и не знаю как он работает
да и как называется тоже
но суть в том что условно можно вызвать весь класс как функцию
типа такого **new Function()**

в общем при инициализации выполняется твоя функция и сразу IDisposable её убивает

у меня есть class Session
в нём я слушаю клиента по TCP
после того как я получил от него пакет , полученный массив buffer отправляю в функцию Handler

при каждом новом клиенте , я заношу его в ClientsManager
в таком случае у меня создаётся много копий Session под каждого клиента

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace server
{
    class Session : IDisposable
    {
        private byte[] buffer;
        private Socket socket { get; set; }
        public Session(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            ClientsManager.online++;
            buffer = new byte[2];
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, End2Bytes, null);
        }
        private void End2Bytes(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                if (socket.EndReceive(result) >= 2)
                {
                    var length = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
                    buffer = new byte[length];
                    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, EndReadBytes, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    Disconnect(); // Отключаем клиента с не понятными пакетами
                    Console.WriteLine("socket.EndReceive(result) < 2"); // Пакеты меньше 2 байт
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) // Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        private void EndReadBytes(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                if (socket.EndReceive(result) == buffer.Length && buffer.Length >= 2) new Handler(buffer); // было Handler(buffer);
                buffer = new byte[2];
                socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, End2Bytes, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) // Удаленный хост разорвал существующее подключение
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
        private void Disconnect()
        {
            socket.BeginDisconnect(false, EndDisconnect, null);
        }
        private void EndDisconnect(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            socket.EndDisconnect(result);
            socket.Disconnect(false);
            ClientsManager.getInstance().clients.Remove(this);
            ClientsManager.online--;
            Dispose();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            socket = null;
            buffer = null;
        }
        ~Session()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        //private void Handler(byte[] buffer) // Перенесён в класс Handler
        //{ 
        //}
    }
}
```

изначально я держал в классе Session функцию Handler()
и посоветовали мне вынести Handler в отдельный класс , молвь зачем ты память забиваешь одним и тем же Handler'ом ?
представь - сколько клиентов столько копий Обработчика (Handler'a)

вынести его в отдельный класс
и вызывай его не Handler(buffer); а **new** Handler(buffer);
ну а в классе Обработчика напиши вот так :

```
using System.IO;
namespace server
{
    class Handler
    {
        public Handler(byte[] buffer)
        {
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
            {
                var opcode = br.ReadUInt16();
                switch (opcode)
                {
                    case 0000: { break; } // Disconnect
                    case 0001: { break; } // Version
                    case 0002: { break; } // Check Login & Password // Answer ID
                    default: { Console.WriteLine("Unknown OpCode : " + opcode ) ; break; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в общем собственно вопрос :
при вызове команды **new Handler(buffer)**
я вызываю функцию из другого класса ?
или создаётся копия у каждой сессии ?
по суть это же очень большая нагрузка будет на сервер
когда существует 100 клиентов , у каждого своя сессия , и каждая сессия
создаёт каждый раз новый Handler что бы обработать 1 пакет
а от одного клиента в 1 секунду прилетает около 60 пакетов
или он просто вызывает как функцию ?

можно было бы создать публичный статический класс
в нём **public static void Get(buffer)**
и вызывать в сессии просто как **Handler.Get(buffer)**

но тогда мне кажется будет забитый поток
то есть пока сессия к примеру игрока **A** запускает **Handler.Get(buffer)**
в это время начинает действовать сессия игрока **B** и ждёт пока **Handler.Get(buffer)** освободится от игрока **A**

или я заблуждаюсь ?
что посоветуете ?
и разъясните что такое new Function()
как он работает ? или это по факту одно и тоже что статическая функция в другом классе
или при вызове **Handler.Get(buffer)** тоже будет создаваться копия ?
тогда какой лучше для производительности ?

> и что лучше использовать , как по производительней ?
>
> 1) обработчик прям в классе session
>
> 2) создавать новый класс и во время инициализации обрабатывать ?
>
> 3) или сделать статическую функцию в
>
> другом классе и вызывать его из каждой сессии ?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Кстати, у вас финализатор полностью бесполезен.

Answer (score 1):

Вам насоветовали что-то странное (ну или вы не поняли совета).

Методы не "занимают память" внутри экзепляров класса. Т.е. ваш

```
private void Handler(byte[] buffer) // Перенесён в класс Handler
{ 
}
```

не займет "дополнительную память внутри каждого `Session`". Код сам по себе - общий для всех объектов Session. Память для каждого экземпляра занимают только поля класса. Вот ваши поля класса Session:

```
private byte[] buffer;
private Socket socket { get; set; }
```

А вот выделение `Handler` в отдельный класс, да еще и создание его для каждого вызова (через new) - действительно создает новые экзепляры Handler для каждого вызова new Handler, отъедая при этом память (правда, ненадолго, и незначительно). Т.е. второй вариант хуже (чуть-чуть) по памяти, чем первый.